# Outlook.com and Google Apps email notifier for gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, email, notification, google

So, pretty basic question,

I use outlook.com for some work email, I use multiple Google Apps emails for different things.

I don't use an email client, I just use the different webmail interfaces,

What I am hoping I can find is an email notifier that can check outlook.com emails, and multiple Google Apps emails and gives me a notification?

Comment: Can you try if [popper](https://launchpad.net/popper) works for you.

Comment: @Capt.Nemo How do I install it? add the `ppa:ralf.hersel/rhersel-ppa` ppa is returning a 404 on `apt-get update`

Answer (score 5):

I would set it up like this:

**The Google Apps Mail**

Instal unity-mail & unity-webapps-gmail

```
sudo apt-get install unity-mail unity-webapps-gmail
```

Open Unity mail and configure it for Google Apps. Setting it up is [almost the same as](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/77654?hl=en) for a gmail account, except for the username which is your_mail@yourdomail.com

You can even set it up with URL so that when you click a mail under the message notification tray you will go directly to the inbox...

**The Outlook.com mail**

Unfortunately Outlook.com does not support IMAP yet, so I would set up forwarding to a gmail account I would create only for this purpose and then set up a second account in unity mail..

Alternatively you can use extentions for your browser:
If you are using chrome go for [Outlok.com notifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/outlookcom-notifier/mkmomflkhdooajekmffpilpoenndjppk)
And if you use Firefox: [X-Notifier](http://xnotifier.tobwithu.com/dp/#post-2271)